# What kind of resolution is CDCL corresponding to?

Tags: sat, resolution

For an unsatisfiable CNF instance, [CDCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-driven_clause_learning) will return a resolution refutation.

**My question** : what kind of resolution does it return? tree-like, regular or general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CDCL with restarts is more or less equivalent to general resolution, see [Pipatsrisawat & Darwiche](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.artint.2010.10.002). CDCL without restarts is more difficult to pin down. It sits somewhere between regular and general resolution; it can be formalized as either pool resolution or regWRTI. See [Bonet, Buss & Johannsen](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/poolVsRegular2/) for a discussion. For a general survey, see §7.3 in [Buss & Nordström’s chapter](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/ProofComplexitySAT/) in the Handbook of Satisfiability.

Comment: Moreover, I want to confirm that DPLL will return a tree-like and regular resolution right?

Comment: Yes. Note that there is no difference between tree-like and tree-like regular resolution (any tree-like refutation can be made regular by omitting redundant branches).